# Open email with subject line that redirects to a new page

Tags: html, redirect, href, html-email

I was trying to use an email address with a subject that will redirect to a new page. I have already done that before and it was working fine but today I am having trouble to work with this!

- The email should be: `reg.immunology@succinctcomms.com`
- The subject line should be: `Registered interest | EADV Fight Club | Wednesday 9th October 2019 | Madrid&body=Please accept this email as confirmation that I would like to register to attend the Janssen Exchange Fight Club event at EADV. [Insert name]%0A%0A[Insert place of work]%0A%0A[Insert any dietary requirements]`
- Destination should be: `http://janssenmedicalcloud.co.uk/exchange-hub/EADV-Dermatology-Webinar-2019?ea=pHhMpRmzH2`

I can not use JS because I am working on an email template.

Any kind of suggestion or help would be very appreciatable.

```html
mailto:reg.immunology@succinctcomms.com?subject=Registered interest | EADV Fight Club | Wednesday 9th October 2019 | Madrid&body=Please accept this email as confirmation that I would like to register to attend the Janssen Exchange Fight Club event at EADV. [Insert name]%0A%0A[Insert place of work]%0A%0A[Insert any dietary requirements]&destination=http://janssenmedicalcloud.co.uk/exchange-hub/EADV-Dermatology-Webinar-2019?ea=pHhMpRmzH2"
```

Comment: `https://www.janssenmedicalcloud.co.uk/emailredirect` is redirecting itself

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. Perhaps `reg.immunology@succinctcomms.com` no longer redirects. I am not sure what the two lines have in common

Comment: Can you please check the post now, I have updated it. @mplungjan

Comment: Would be useful to see more of the example. For instance is this an anchor link with `<a href="` at the start of it?

Comment: If the server receiving the email stopped redirecting, then you need to talk to them

Comment: any error ? what is currently happening with above code?

Comment: @NagaSaiA The mail is not opening not even it's redirecting